# How to compute and display the result of a column in a datagrid?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I am Trying to compute data from a single column in a datagridview. Any idea how?
I also need it to be displayed on a label..

I am using vb.net
also mySQL for my database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sums a column

```
mylabel.text = Convert.ToDouble(CType(DGV.DataSource, DataTable).Compute("SUM(MyColumn)", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to every value of a cell at row "i" and column "x" by using the for-construct. This example shows how to get the sum of each value in the column "x" and set it to a lable.

```
Dim sum As Double = 0
With Me.myDGV
    For i = 0 To .RowCount - 1
        Dim value As Double = .Rows(i).Cells(x).Value
        'compute something with the value, for example add to a sum
        sum = sum + value
    Next
End With
Me.myLabel.text = sum.ToString
```